# SWR pagination with object as search queries

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I have been using SWR for pagination to display data on the page. At first it was a simple API with 2 query strings: `page` and `size`.

```js
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

const { data, error } = useSWR(
  `/api/pager?page=${pageIndex}&size=${pageSize}`,
  fetcher
);
```

So far so good. Now I want to add search feature to the data. The search criteria can be complex. Apart from searching on string, I also want to search on Date, score and some other fields. Putting them in the URL search queries seems not efficient as the URL will become sooooo long.

```js
const searchCriteria = {
  description: "some foo",
  startDate: new Date("2023-04-01"),
  endDate: new Date("2023-04-30"),
  submitted: true
}
```

Is there a way to do pagination with SWR by providing an object? The official [doc](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#passing-objects) looks vague to me. Appreciate if example code can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the API then use `POST` method and send your data in the `body`:

```
const fetcher = ({ url, data }) => fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then((res) => res.json());

const searchCriteria = {
  description: "some foo",
  startDate: new Date("2023-04-01"),
  endDate: new Date("2023-04-30"),
  submitted: true
}

const { data, error } = useSWR({
    url: `/api/pager`,
    data: { ...searchCriteria. page: pageIndex, size: pageSize  }
  },
  fetcher
);
```

Otherwise you can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to concatenate your search params with the url:

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchCriteria);

const { data, error } = useSWR(
  `/api/pager?page=${pageIndex}&size=${pageSize}&${searchParams.toString()}`,
  fetcher
);
```

Comment: BRAVO! Very concise.